# Should I use cookies to speed up responsiveness of dashboard?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, cookies

I have an ASP.net MVC application with a "Wallboard" screen. The problem is that this particular page takes a long time to load (it has to cycle through a bunch of databases and calculate several numbers to be displayed).

When I clicked on the "Wallboard" menu item, the browser wheel would spin for ~30 seconds before bringing up the page. I know this is very obnoxious for users, so I decided to store the previous values of the strings being displayed (last time the page was loaded) in a cookie and instantly load the page with those strings while an AJAX call retrieved newer values.

The page indicates that it's retrieving newer values, but these values don't change that often, so it's useful for the user to be able to see older values right away.

It's working but my question is, are cookies the best way to store this data? The server doesn't really care at all what values are stored, just that the page instantly loads instead of hanging. If the page has never been loaded then the wallboard is blank until the AJAX call completes.

Comment: I would suggest to implement a cache mechanism on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is likely not a good idea, unless it is very small amount of data.

I more appropriate solution would be to use the [Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx)

For example, this will cache the database data for 30 minutes, at which point the cache will expire, so any one who access the page will get a cached version and that will speed up your web site dramatically.

```
Cache.Insert("key", "database-data", null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), TimeSpan.Zero);
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like it's more along the lines of what I was trying to do, but when I tried OutputCache on the action that gets the data, I start getting OutOfMemory exceptions... Seems odd since the output is just a JSON object. Wouldn't figure it would take that much memory.

Comment: @aufty The benefit I found using the Cache object, is to have better control of what/when/how to cache .... as most of the time the OutputCache feels little bit out of control ... or at least for me

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not the right way to store large amounts of data on the client side as they are transferred to the server with every request.

I recommend you to take a look at the [**Local Storage API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

If you need to store a significant amount of data and require common database features, take a look at 
[**IndexedDB**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).